# GoPro footage from App to Computer?

Tags: gopro

I have a GoPro Hero 11, and have saved lots of photos and videos to the Cloud, and the Quik App on my phone.

How can I get the photos/videos from the Quik App to my computer?  The videos are stored in the App - *not* downloaded to my phone.  When I go to download the videos in the app to my phone, it says I don't have enough space.  This is because the app is storing the videos on the phone already --- so I'd effectively be duplicating the videos if I could save them to my phone.

What's the proper method to get the videos off my phone to my computer?  If I copy/paste the video files from the hidden Android folder that stores the Quik App data, will that include everything (GPS info, etc.) that would otherwise be included on Cloud Downloaded video?

Edit: A quick review of the main issue -- Let's say I have an SD card with 100 GB free, and 100 GB Free in my Internal Storage.  When I use Quik to download the videos from the physical GoPro, Quik saves these videos/photos on my *internal storage* in a hidden folder (I need PC access to see it).  At this point, I then have to "Save to Phone", to get the video "out" of the App, onto my Phone for copy/pasting, etc.  The issue here is, say I downloaded 90 GB from GoPro --- 90 GB is taken up in my internal storage, and so when I 'save to phone', it doesn't have space, because those *same files* are already on the internal storage.  I am just looking to find out how to best avoid this ridiculous software issue and pull the video/photos/metadata/telemetry from my App or GoPro itself.

Comment: Maybe you can ask your question here: https://video.stackexchange.com/ or https://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The answer to your last question is "maybe", but it doesn't hurt or cost a penny to try, and you can answer it yourself quite quickly.

Comment: @dandavis - I am not sure how to check a media file for the GPS info, etc. but will go ahead and try I suppose.  It's just doing that, I'm not positive (via any documentation anywhere) that it will include all info as if I pulled via GoPro's software...so will be assuming.

Comment: GoPro's hidden folder structure (in Android) isn't straightforward so doing this is certainly not instilling confidence in my copying the info properly.

Comment: if you're on windows, plug the phone in and open it as a drive, then type one of file known filenames into the little explorer search box to find the folder your app uses to store.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're not bypassing the app/phone altogether, and just plugging a USB cable into the GoPro to your computer and directly downloading photos/videos from the camera?

Comment: Does your phone have a free slot for a (large) memory card? That could allow you to copy/export (I don't like the word "download" here) the media from the Quik app so it's easily accessible on the memory card. Alternatively, how much free space _do_ you have on the phone? Maybe if you start off copying/exporting one video at a time, then delete it in the app, quite quickly you might be able to free up huge chunks of storage space on the phone. It doesn't have to all be done as a single operation, right?

Comment: @inkista the media is no longer on the GoPro at all. It's been deleted from there, because it's already been uploaded to cloud storage and to the OP's phone. That's my understanding.

Comment: @osullic - Yes, I have a SD card over 100 GB.  What's frustrating is that the GoPro Quik App installs on the Internal Memory, and also seems to store the video that I download off the GoPro camera, on the internal memory and I cannot figure out how to move it to my SD card. It's extremely frustrating, because the App stores the video, but then I further have to download from the App to Internal Storage (effectively duplicating the files).  Since my internal storage is full from the APP storage, I can't get the videos off the app to my internal storage, to then copy/paste...if that makes sense.

Comment: @BruceWayne just a minor point on terminology... downloading and uploading are done between different devices (traditionally a client and a server). If you are just (trying to) copy data around an individual device, I wouldn't use the term "download" - for me, this term here confuses the issue.

Comment: @osullic - sorry for the confusion.  I guess then I'm uploading the videos from my GoPro to my Phone (via Quik App).  I then want to download these off the App, and onto my phone where I can actually access the videos outside goPro's App.  [Go Pro] --> [Quik App, stored hidden] --> [Save to phone as .mp4 or whatever].

Answer (score 0):

Downloading photos to a laptop computer is actually quite easy. All you need is the USB cable that you charge your phone with. One end of the cable to the cellphone and the other end in the USB port of the laptop. The laptop will think it another type of flash drive. This process works because the USB cable not only transmits power to a device but  data as well. Even though you have an app to retrieve your photos you might not need to use it. The photos are probably stored in separate folder usually named something like DCIM. Open the folder and all the files tagged .jpg or whatever your favorite format is.These are your photos. Copy and paste your photos into a folder on your laptop and your done. I believe it also works in the opposite direction as well. The GPS, ISO, shutter speed and F-Stop is encoded on the image and is viewable in the file properties.

I imagine this process the process would work on a GoPro if they are set up in the same way.

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of how to copy/paste photos generally.  What I don't know is how/where GoPro stores its telemetry (constant GPS information for a video, etc) - if that's not stored with the `.mp4` (or whatever format GoPro uses)'s meta-data, I am not positive if I have it...so I'm looking for a way to make positive all of the related information from the videos/photos is copied.

Comment: @BruceWayne Have you tried a few to satisfy yourself that it works?